# Access callback for user/%user/edit menu item not working

Tags: routes, users

I have two roles, client & student. Students can edit their profiles, clients cannot. I thought the easiest way to solve this would be to add a permission as per below:

```
function si_permission() {
  return array(
    'edit account' => array(
    'title' => t('Edit account'),
    'description' => t('Allow users to edit their account')
  )
}
```

I then altered the menu item and changed the access callback to my new permission:

```
function si_dashboard_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['user/%user/edit']['access callback'] = user_access('edit account');
}
```

I then set the permission appropriately in permissions settings, but it does not work. It always appears to be false, so the menu item access is always disabled. I have even debugged   'user_access('edit account')' whilst logged in as the appropriate user and it returns TRUE, so I know the permission is working.

All caches cleared, menus rebuilt using developer tools. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it appears I have to set the access as per following:

```
function si_dashboard_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['user/%user/edit']['access callback'] = 'user_access';
  $items['user/%user/edit']['access arguments'] = array('edit account');
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `array('edit account')`? Note that this will mean users with the _Administer users_ permission but without _Edit account_ won't be able to edit any accounts. (Not necessarily a problem, but could be a surprise.)

Comment: @Andy User 1 bypasses anything sent through `user_access()` so that won't be an issue - definitely should be an array, though

Comment: Sorry, just re-read that and it's nonsense. Please ignore :)

Comment: @Andy yes sorry missed that when I typed it up manually.